# Difference Between 2 Dates and Times in Excel

Tags: excel, date, time, excel-formula

I need to calculate the number of hours (excluding weekends and holidays) that pass by between 2 Dates (with times) in Excel.

For example:
7/28/17 10:57   to  7/31/17 12:40

Is there such a formula in Excel (b/c I know Excel can be VERY difficult when dealing with time)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming A2 has start Date time, b2 has end time. use this formula in c2 to calculate time difference. =NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)-1-MOD(A2,1)+MOD(B2,1)

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was using Networkdays but I wasn't doing the "MOD" portions.  Excel is just ridiculously difficult when it comes to time haha.  Thank you again!