# How can I calculate the number of days it takes to process claims in Excel using two dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I am looking to calculate the difference between 2 dates to determine the time taken for claims processing.

I have a field in my excel called payment date and another field called alert date. I want to subtract these 2 date field to calculate the number of days it took to process the claim.

These dates can be like 01/07/2022 being the payment date and incident date being 07/12/2020.

I am trying to use the formula `=DATEDIF(M2,B2,"d")` and it is giving weird results as in `24/7/1900` which makes no sense. I need the output column to have the total number of days it took to process the payment from the time the claim was alerted. Could someone please help and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: M2 being the alert date and B2 being the payment date

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591038/difference-between-2-dates-and-times-in-excel. A simple search in SO turns up a number of answers. You could have found those in less time than it took to post your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference Between 2 Dates and Times in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591038/difference-between-2-dates-and-times-in-excel)

Comment: Pls. take in consideration the previous comments. Otherwise, the result has sense, it's value is 206. This is the number format of the date you get as a result.

Comment: The result is formatted as a date. If you change the format to general or number you see the result you expected.

Comment: It gives you weird results because in Excel when some functions are applied in cells or dragged down, it not only copies but also carry forwards the formatting itself to another cell, You need to either format them to general or number to get the desired output as is already commented by @P.b here ^^^. Also I think your query is best suited for **[Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel)**

Answer (score 1):

Built this to show two methods:

1. very simple just taking the difference and
2. using datedif()

[image]

Both need to be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

While reading your question i see you already used datediff . Yes we can process this into way either subtracting one column with other or by using datediff.

"I am trying to use the formula =DATEDIF(M2,B2,"d") and it is giving weird results as in 24/7/1900"

To handle this issue where you are getting weird input by changing the datatype from formatting pane . Press Ctrl  + ! and within option chooose number.

I hope that will help you .